# How to get my Google Sheets Query's to automatically pull from a Year dropdown tab?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kXFh-OWeFxFKuqnX9WAP3JDwo9cz5cR73Z4bp0IUVTo/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to get my query functions to automatically update based on the year that is selected in the drop down tab.

I have this for the Prospects table:

```
=Query('BNTouch Raw Data'!$A$1:CL,"
SELECT AF, sum(L), avg(L), count(L)
WHERE BO contains 'Prospect' and BD >= Date '2021-01-01' and BD <= Date '2021-12-31'
GROUP by AF
ORDER BY sum(L) desc
LIMIT 7
LABEL sum(L) 'Total Loan Amount', count(L) 'Loan Quantity', avg(L) 'Average Loan Amount' ")
```

and thought maybe to put in the 'Where line item' the range that I calculated in Sheet Inputs - ColumnCL2 & ColumnCL3.

so something like:

```
WHERE BO contains 'Prospect' and BD >= Date 'CL2' and BD <= Date 'CL3'
```

but clearly that doesn't work. Any ideas on how to get the queries to update automatically when the dropdown year is selected?

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=Query('BNTouch Raw Data'!$A$1:CL,"
 SELECT AF, sum(L), avg(L), count(L)
 WHERE BO contains 'Prospect' 
   and BD >= Date '"&TEXT(CL2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
   and BD <= Date '"&TEXT(CL3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
 GROUP by AF
 ORDER BY sum(L) desc
 LIMIT 7
 LABEL sum(L) 'Total Loan Amount', count(L) 'Loan Quantity', avg(L) 'Average Loan Amount' ")
```

Comment: I used your Date ranges formula and it looks like the grouping doesn't populated i.e. the table is calculating but the data doesn't pull through. any ideas?

Comment: @wilt can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

@player0

I was able to use your advice to get to this:

```
=Query('BNTouch Raw Data'!$A$1:CN,
if($I$9<>"","
SELECT AF, sum(L), avg(L), count(L)
WHERE BO contains 'Prospect' 
 and BD >= date """&TEXT($F$9,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" 
 and BD <= date """&TEXT($F$11,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"""
 and AF = '"&$I$9&"'
GROUP by AF
ORDER BY sum(L) desc
LIMIT 16
LABEL sum(L) 'Total Loan Amount', count(L) 'Loan Quantity', avg(L) 'Average Loan Amount' ","
SELECT AF, sum(L), avg(L), count(L)
WHERE BO contains 'Prospect' 
 and BD >= date """&TEXT($F$9,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" 
 and BD <= date """&TEXT($F$11,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"""
GROUP by AF
ORDER BY sum(L) desc
LIMIT 16
LABEL sum(L) 'Total Loan Amount', count(L) 'Loan Quantity', avg(L) 'Average Loan Amount' "))
```